# localhost Wordpress site just downloads php file but won't serve the site itself

Tags: xampp

I installed xampp and even downloaded a fresh wordpress from official site. It is running fine. 
But when i try to load my existing live site in localhost, it just downloads the php file but won't serve the site. 
What is it that i am missing? 
It runs fine in my friend's windows machine but not on my ubuntu. 
I even changed chmod permissions to the folder for it to be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a WordPress specific problem. And maybe a duplicate question of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing